# Change input field height based on the content inside in Bootstrap

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, input, word-wrap

I am trying to fit content inside the bootstrap input field and it is not even binding. Please find the code line in which I need to adjust height as the content size increases.

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" 
name="typeOfOwnership"  
[(ngModel)]="newJson?.basicDetails.typeOfOwnership[0].typeOfOwnershipName" 
readonly>
```

[image]

Comment: You mean your content runs in multiple lines is it ?

Comment: What do you mean change the height of input? with increase size of content width can change not height, right? otherwise you can use textArea for multiline, if you want to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your content is bigger, you should be using a **Textarea** instead.

try using this

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="newJson?.basicDetails.typeOfOwnership[0].typeOfOwnershipName" readonly></textarea>
```